# Can't figure out why this regex doesn't apply

Tags: proxy, regex, rewrite

I am using Privoxy 3.0.10.0 to filter web pages before they're passed on to the browser.

I can't figure out why this simple regex doesn't trigger a rewrite. Maybe someone more experienced will have an idea:

Here's what it looks like when I hit Firefox's CTRL-U to view the HTML source:

```
<font color=#FF4AFF>JohnDoe</font>
```

Here's my regex; I've also added the "i" switch to ignore case, to no avail

```
s|(<font color=.+?>JohnDoe</font>)|<span class=myclass>$1</span>|g
```

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to serverfault?

Comment: Given RichieHindle's answer: are you sure you want to embed **the full** original within `<span>` tags, or did you expect only the `JohnDoe` part to be copied, like `<span class=myclass>JohnDoe</span>`? Just to make sure that you're not overlooking `<span class=myclass><font color=#FF4AFF>JohnDoe</font></span>` in the result.

Answer (score 4):

The regex itself works fine, as this Python example shows:

```
import re
print re.sub(r"(<font color=.+?>JohnDoe</font>)",
             r"<span class=myclass>\1</span>",
             "<font color=#FF4AFF>JohnDoe</font>")
# Prints <span class=myclass><font color=#FF4AFF>JohnDoe</font></span>
```

(assuming Privoxy uses the same regex syntax, barring the `\1` vs. `$1` difference, but it looks like it does.)

I guess the problem lies elsewhere - try a regex that can't fail, like replacing `a` with `b`, to see whether it's having any effect at all.

Answer (score 2):

Thansk guys. Turns out Privoxy was greedy, and I didn't notice that it was taking much more data than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what RE engine you're using, but try changing the $1 to \1 - that's how backreferences are usually referred to in perl, at least.

Comment: Sometimes you'll need to use \\1, depending on in what format you're writing the regex.

Comment: In Apache's URL rewriting, one would use $1. But, if \1 should indeed be used in this case, then I'd expect the output to be `<span class=myclass>$1</span>` -- which hopefully would have been noted in the question then...